# How to prevent the Stanford POS tagger from splitting sentences?

Tags: stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

How can I prevent the Stanford POS tagger from doing sentence splitting?

My text is already split into sentences and tokens, one sentence per line. I just want the POS tag for each token.

The number of lines and tokens in the output should equal the number of lines and tokens in the input.

Example:

```
$ echo ". . . a b c . . . d e f" \
  | java \
     -classpath stanford-postagger.jar \
                edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger \
     -prop myPropsFile.prop \
     -model models/german-fast.tagger
._$. ._$. ._$.

a_XY b_XY c_FM ._$. ._$. ._$.

d_FM e_FM f_VVFIN
```

The output I was expecting would be something like:

```
._$. ._$. ._$. a_XY b_XY c_FM ._$. ._$. ._$. d_FM e_FM f_VVFIN
```

I already put `tokenize=false` into my props file, but it still splits the sentences. (It also puts an empty line between sentences in the output, which is undesired.)

Comment: I see that sentence splitting does not occur when the input is in a file specified with `-textFile`, but I need it in a (Hadoop) streaming context, where this is not an option.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Stanford mailing-list? Their techs usually answer queries rapidement!